# update mysql stored-procedure on live site

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, rds

my site is live on AWS ,my all queries are in stored-procedure only, for some reason i have to update old stored-procedure into it, is it a good idea to update RDS on live site, or should do it in maintenance.

1:if i don't want to do it in maintenance then what are the option i have ?.

2:what are the best approach to update tables & stored-procedure in future without being down site.

Comment: Why do you have a maintenance period if you are not going to use it to update code?

Comment: because it take to much time to update in RDS, & i don't want to down my site for hr or more. thats why i am searching for alternate way to do that. the better way.

Comment: Why is it necessary to take the site down for an hour or more just to replace a stored procedure?  This only requires a few seconds.